# How to use foldr in Racket to eliminate numbers in a list that are greater than any subsequent numbers

Tags: racket, fold, higher-order-functions

I have to write a function in Racket using foldr that will take a list of numbers and remove list elements that are larger than any subsequent numbers.

Example: (eliminate-larger (list 1 2 3 5 4)) should produce (1 2 3 4)

I can do it without using foldr or any higher-order functions but I can't figure it out with foldr. Here's what I have:

```
(define (eliminate-larger lst)
   (filter (lambda (z) (not(equal? z null))) 
       (foldr (lambda (x y) 
           (cons (determine-larger x (rest lst)) y)) null lst))                    
)

(define (determine-larger value lst)
   (if (equal? (filter (lambda (x) (>= x value)) lst) lst)
       value
       null)
)
```

determine-larger will take in a value and a list and return that value if it is greater than or equal to all elements in the list. If not, it returns null. Now the eliminate-larger function is trying to go through the list and pass each value to determine-larger along with a list of every number after it. If it is a "good" value it will be returned and put in the list, if it's not a null is put in the list. Then at the end the nulls are being filtered out. My problem is getting the list of numbers that follow after the current number in the foldr function. Using "rest lst" doesn't work since it's not being done recursively like that. How do I get the rest of the numbers after x in foldr?

Answer (score 1):

I really hope I'm not doing your homework for you, but here goes ...

> How do I get the rest of the numbers after x in foldr?

Because you're consuming the list *from the right*, you can structure your accumulator such that "the rest of the numbers after x" are available as its `memo` argument.

```
(define (eliminate-larger lst)
  (foldr 
    (lambda (member memo)
       (if (andmap (lambda (n) (<= member n)) memo)
         (cons member memo)
         memo)) 
    '()
    lst))
(eliminate-larger (list 1 2 3 5 4)) ;; (1 2 3 4)
```

This is admittedly a naive solution, as you're forced to traverse the entire accumulator with each iteration, but you could easily maintain a max value, in addition to your memo, and compare against that each time through.

Comment: That works, thanks! I'm trying to read about how andmap works but am not quite following what it is doing.

Comment: `andmap` is being used to verify that `member` is `<=` every element in the accumulator list. As compared to using a function like `filter`, it has the added benefit of returning early if _any_ application of the supplied proc returns `#f` (e.g. `(<= 5 4)`).

Comment: @KeithCalderwood If you're satisfied with this answer, would you mind accepting it?

Answer (score 0):

Following works:

```
(define  (el lst)
  (define  (inner x lsti)
    (if(empty? lsti) (list x)
       (if(<= x (apply max lsti))
          (cons x lsti)
          lsti)))
  (foldr inner '() lst))

(el (list 1 2 3 5 4))
```

Output:

```
'(1 2 3 4)
```

The cond version may be preferable:

```
(define  (el lst)
  (define  (inner x lsti)
    (cond 
      [(empty? lsti) (list x)]
      [(<= x (apply max lsti))  (cons x lsti)]
      [else lsti]  ))
  (foldr inner '() lst) )
```